# Previous images do not disappear after keyboard inputs

Tags: graphics

I'm working on keyboard function that moves up, down, left, right and forward&backward. They seems to work okay, but the problem is that the previous object images still appears. It's like after images are spread all over the screen.

Below are my codes.

**This in an initial setting for variables:**

```
double x1 = 0.0f;
double yi = 1.0f;
double z1 = 3.0f;

double lx1 = 0.0f;
double ly1 = 0.0f;
double lz1 = -1.0f;

double angle = 0.0f;
```

**Keyboard function:**

```
switch (key) {

case 033: 
    glutLeaveMainLoop();
    break;
case 'd':
    angle -= 0.01f;
    lx1 = sin(angle);
    lz1 = -cos(angle);
    //setCamera();
    break;
case 'a':
    angle += 0.01f;
    lx1 = sin(angle);
    lz1 = -cos(angle);
    //setCamera();
    break;
case 's':
    angle += 0.01f;
    ly1 = angle;
    //setCamera();
    break;
case 'w':
    angle -= 0.01f;
    ly1 = angle;
    //setCamera();
    break;
case '2' :
    x1= (-1) * lx1 * 0.1 + x1;
    z1 = (-1) * lz1 * 0.1 + z1;
    //setCamera();
    break;
case '1':
    x1 = (1) * lx1 * 0.1 + x1;
    z1 = (1) * lz1 * 0.1 + z1;
    //setCamera();
    break;
}

glutPostRedisplay(); }
```

**and**

```
void setCamera() {
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(x1, yi, z1, x1 + lx1, yi + ly1, z1 + lz1, 0, 1, 0); 
}
```

There is `setCamera()` function in `display()` function as well. What I thought about this was every time I type inputs, variables that are inserted in `gluLookAt()` function gets updated and will draw a new image by `glutPostRedisplay()`, whereas former image remains. Are there anything I'd overlook?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `glClear()` at the beginning of your draw method?

Comment: Yes. I have a
`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`
 at the beginning of my display function... @NicoSchertler

Comment: Can you show the function and a screenshot?

Comment: Do you mean by display function?
`void display() {
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear the screen and depth buffer
 setCamera();            // Setup Camera's position and direction

                // Draw your objects here
 drawTeapot();
 drawArma();

 glFlush();
     
 g_frame += 1; 
}`
Screenshot was added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Because this function is ultimately responsible for what you see. Not the input handling function.